# Batch file to copy files in many subfolders

Tags: batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy multiple files (just files) that:

1. its name contains defined string
2. files are in many sub-folders
3. to be copied in a created folder "all files in one folder not a folder tree"
4. duplicated files to have new numbering sequence
5. the root folder is the folder that contains the .bat file

I tried the following:

```
@Echo OFF
Set "Pattern=status"
Set "destinationFolder=c:\xxx\03-Ins\01-Mad\copied_files"
For /R %%G in (*.xlsx) Do (
    Echo %%~nxG | FIND "%Pattern%" 1>NUL && (
        Echo Full Path: %%~G
        COPY %%G "%destinationFolder%\"%%~nxG
    )
)
Pause&Exit
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing it like that. What's wrong with using `"*%Pattern%*.xlsx"` instead of grabbing everything from `*.xlsx`, then running them all through an `Echo` command piped to `FIND`.exe. Also, `"%destinationFolder%\"%%~nxG` should be `"%destinationFolder%\%%~nxG"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Echo OFF

set "Pattern=status"
Set "destinationFolder=c:\xxx\03-Ins\01-Mad\copied_files"

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /r %%G in (*.xlsx) do (
    set /a count+=1
    echo %%~nxG | find "%Pattern%" 1>NUL && (
        echo Full Path: %%~G
        copy "%%~G" "%destinationFolder%\%%~nxG_!count!"
    )
    @rem echo [!count!]: %%~nxG
)
Pause&Exit
```